# How to authenticate clients trying to access my website via my external IP address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, port-forwarding

I have made a ruby on rails app which is running on `0.0.0.0:3000`
I have also forwarded the port 3000 on my router so that it is accessible remotely via the internet.
So, I can view the webapp by the following ways:
1. `localhost:3000` on the machine on which the server is running on
2. `192.168.0.100:3000` on any machine on the same LAN
3. `<my-external-ip>:3000` on any machine connected to the internet

Now, how can I add a login authentication system such that whenever someone enters `<my-external-ip>:3000` on their browser, they have to enter a username and password before they can access the webapp. I know I can add an authentication system in my Ruby on Rails app, but I was hoping for a solution which does it 'before' the Rails layer.

I am completely new to this.

Comment: This belongs on a different stack.  Likely Ask Ubuntu or Unix and Linux.

Comment: You can configure another webserver as reverse proxy and enforce authentication from there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a nginx reverse proxy on the application machine with the following configuration for the default site:

```
server {
listen 3001;

server_name _;

auth_basic "Restricted Access";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}}
```

From there, generate a relevant htpasswd file with a username and password (see http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ or `apache-utils`) and place it at `/etc/nginx/htpasswd.users`.

On your router, have the external port 3000 map to the internal IP at port 3001.

From there, when someone from the outside tries to access your site, it will prompt them for a username and password.

Note, this is completely unencrypted, and has no protection against brute force attacks, but for what you are looking for, it will work well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, solved my problem!